# MySql Update records with existing and new values in bulk insert

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I am confused to how to deal with the below scenario.

I have `product` table and i'm inserting records in this table using bulk insert.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO product (p_id,p_quantity) VALUES(1,20),(2,10),(3,30);
```

Now I want update `p_quantity` if `p_id` is already exists.

e.g. my next bulk insert query can be

```
INSERT INTO product (p_id,p_quantity) VALUES(2,15),(4,40);
```

So, in such case my product having `p_id = 2` should get updated with `15` and total `p_quantity` should be `25`.

NOTE: I can not apply unique key constraints on any of key as  I have other scenarios.

Thank you.

Comment: Please tag a specific Database

Comment: Create primary/unique index by `p_id` if not exists.Use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=811a46edb0b208509a11c181858c2f09).

Comment: 'I can not apply unique key constraints on any of key as I have other scenarios' - are you saying you cannot create a primary or unique key on p_id?

Comment: i have primary key but i cant create unique key hence i cant use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE also.  @P.Salmon

Comment: A primary key is a unique key and if it is on p_id then you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO product (p_id, p_quantity)
    VALUES (2,15), (4,40)
    ON DUPLICATE UPDATE p_quantity = VALUES(p_quantity) + p_quantity;
```

This assumes that `p_id` is defined as `unique` or `primary key`.

Answer (score -2):

If p_id is already exist you need to update it

UPDATE product
SET p_quantity = 15
WHERE p_id = 2

Then second record will be updated. After that you can insert 4th record

Comment: No. This is not smart.

Comment: You will attract down votes because this does not address the OPs requirement to use BULK INSERT and the intention was to change p_quantity to 25 not 15.